# Maclaurin series expansion

Tags: calculus

Write the Maclaurin series for: $6\cos{5x^2}$

Find the first five coefficients.

For this question: I repeatedly come to the answer of: $6-75 x^4+\frac{625 x^8}{4}+O(x^9)$

With the coefficients being $6, -75, \frac{625}{4}$ and $0$. These answers are wrong though.

Any suggestions on how to get the 2nd, 3rd, 4th, and fifth coeffient? I have coefficient #1 correct.

Comment: Maybe there is a misunderstanding as to what first second and all that mean. Note that most of the coefficients are $0$.

Comment: hmmm, I see. Did you get the same expansion as I for this?

Comment: The term in $x^4$ is $-(6)(25)/2!$, the term in $x^8$ is $(6)(625)/24$, so we agree.

Comment: ACTUALLY! I realized that every other coeffiencient is basically a 0. Therefore it is kinda like my expansion with zeros in between that I neglected! Thank you for the clarity!

Comment: That's the correct expansion, yes. So the only relevant point is whether they want the first five _nonzero_ terms, and that's not really a problem of math anymore...

Comment: You are welcome. That is what I was trying to point out, since it is a possible source of ambiguity. It can be reasonable not to "see" $0$ stuff.

Comment: Exactly why I wasn't considering the zeros... Thanks for bringing that ambiguity to light Andre :)

Answer (score 3):

$$
\cos x = 1 - \frac{x^2}{2!} + \frac{x^4}{4!} - \frac{x^6}{6!} + \frac{x^8}{8!} - \ldots
$$
Thus,
$$
6\cos(5x^2) = 6\biggl[1 - \frac{(5x^2)^2}{2} + \frac{(5x^2)^4}{24} - \frac{(5x^2)^6}{720} + \frac{(5x^2)^8}{40320} - \ldots \biggr]
$$